# Why you would choose "a.out file" over "a.out < file" or vice versa? c++

Tags: c++, unix, command-line

I guess I'm having a hard time understanding the differences. This is important because how would the user know what to type at the command line? At the command line, *a.out file* is for file processing where you need to explicitly open the file. *a.out < file* is redirected input and you don't need to open the file. Pros and cons?

Comment: Depends whether the program uses `stdin` or whether it uses a file stream.

Comment: So a.out < file uses stdin, right? And how would the user know stdin is used?

Comment: They're not the same thing, and are not interchangeable. Accepting a filename as a parameter is not the same thing as receiving input from `stdin`. There are no "pros and cons" - it's an apples and oranges question. This has nothing to do with what the user knows; they'd have to know up front which your program supported (or whether it accepted both) in advance, and the only way to know that is documentation.

Comment: Thank you @KenWhite. Okay, I think I got it. I'm also now understanding that stdin could be used by typing a filename or typing the file contents at the command line.

Comment: It's really just a matter of what OS you're on. *nix apps tend to be very liberal with stdin/stdout usage, while Windows apps tends to prefer operating on files. Many apps will accept both forms, usually having the user specify "-" for the file name to mean stdin/stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stdin is particularly useful when you want to be able to pipe the output of one program to the input of another program, and so on in a chain, like this:

```
cat myfile.txt | grep MyKeyword | wc -l
```

(which will print out the number of lines in myfile.txt containing the string MyKeyword)

If the "grep" and "wc" utilities were set up to only read from a specified file, rather than from stdin, the above task would be more difficult; you'd have to do it in multiple steps instead:

```
grep MyKeyword myfile.txt > temp.txt
wc -l temp.txt
rm temp.txt
```

... which would be awkward and also requires writing a temporary file to the disk, which can be problematic (e.g. what if there was already a temp.txt file in the current directory?  Oops, you just overwrote it, too bad!  Or what if you don't have write-access to the drive?  No way to write out a temporary file then)

On the other hand, sometimes your program needs to read from more than one file.  For example, if you wanted to concatenate several files together you can do this:

cat part1.txt part2.txt part3.txt > wholething.txt

If "cat" only supported reading from stdin it would be difficult to do such a thing, as you'd need some way to pipe multiple files into cat's stdin stream.

Also, if a program needed to read the file in non-linear order (e.g. fseek() forward or back in the file rather than just reading it straight through) it wouldn't be able to do that using stdin, since you can't seek on a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard Unix idiom where a 'filter' program will read each of the files specified on the command line, or read from standard input if there are no files specified on the command line, and write the output to standard output.  Examples of such filters are `sort` and `grep`.  The program `tr` is one of the rare exceptions that is a pure filter; it only reads standard input and only writes to standard output.

The advantage of accepting file names on the command line is that a single invocation of the program can read multiple files; the program can also identify which file each line of input comes from.  The advantage of reading standard input is that you don't have to write code to open files.  Obviously, there are ways to handle a program that does not read files; for example, you can use `cat` to read the file and pipe the output to the standard input of the program.  The downside is that the program cannot tell which file any given line came from (even if it is a single file redirected).

Thus the two notations are not, in general, equivalent.  Both are useful.  Many useful programs support both notations.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `cin>>` in your program and you don't want to provide input from keyboard then store it in a file (say file) and use `./a.out < file`. it's called input redirection.

`./a.out file` means nothing.

`./a.out < file > file_output` means take input from `file` and write the output of the program in `file_output`

Comment: `./a.out file` means you're passing a command-line argument.